consteval: Why evaluation of a compound requires inside a consteval lambda is not a constant expression?
I just started using C++20/23 and did some tests around using consteval lambda alongside with requires expressions.
struct Node {
    Node* found_mem;
    static constexpr auto field_found_mem = &Node::found_mem;
};

template<typename T>
struct List {
    static constexpr auto found_mem_member_ptr = []()consteval{
        if constexpr(requires(T v){
            { v.found_mem } -> std::convertible_to<T*&>;
        }) {
            return &T::found_mem;
        } else {
            return T::field_found_mem;
        }
    }(); // Error: Call to consteval function 'List<Node>::(anonymous class)::operator()' is not a constant expression

    static constexpr auto found_mem_member_ptr1 = []()consteval{
        if constexpr(requires(T v){
            { v.not_found_member } -> std::convertible_to<T*&>;
        }) {
            return &T::not_found_member;
        } else {
            return &T::found_mem;
        }
    }(); // Error: No member named 'not_found_member' in 'Node'

    static constexpr auto found_mem_member_ptr2 = []()consteval{
        if  constexpr(requires(T v){
            v.not_found_member;
        }) return &T::not_found_member;
        else return &T::found_mem;
    }(); // Compiles.

    static constexpr auto get_found_mem_member_ptr3(){
        if  constexpr(requires(T v){
            { v.not_found_member } -> std::convertible_to<T*&>;
        }) return &T::not_found_member;
        else return &T::found_mem;
    } // Also compiles.
    static constexpr auto found_mem_member_ptr3 = get_found_mem_member_ptr3();
};

static void func() {
    List<Node> l1;
};

Are there any additional restrictions for compound requirements to be used in this context? Appreciate any advices.

Environments:
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.0.0
Thread model: posix

Compiling with C++23, -std=c++2b.

Update: It seems like a bug with the Xcode 15.3 bundled clang. The code compiles fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/Wx9za5aYK
